# OAuth2.0 for an iframe widget

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a website with a public API:

```
mysite.com
api.mysite.com (protected with OAuth2.0)
```

My website will allow other website owners to place an iframe widget on their page, similar to a Facebook friends widget. When a consumer logs in to the widget, I need it to communicate with my public API. I currently have a 3-legged auth set up:

1. Use clientId to request code
2. Use clientId, clientSecret, and code to request accessToken
3. Make API calls like this:

   ```
   https://api.mysite.com/me?access_token=12345
   ```

My API is stateless (no sessions), and relies on the access token to authenticate every request. How do I set up my javascript widget to communicate with my OAuth2 API? My first thought was to store the access token in a cookie, but I know that isn't secure.

Comment: Will the content of the iFrame be hosted on your site (<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com"></iframe> )? If so, then why do you need to use the public API? The content of the frame is from your server.

Comment: The content of the iFrame will be hosted from the API <iframe src="api.mysite.com"></iframe>